# Can't add ProgressIndicators (app crashes)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

When I use any kind of Progress Indicators like `CircularProgressIndicator()` or `LinearProgressIndicator()` my app crashes:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method at(Ljava/lang/Object;I)
  Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframeEntity; in class
  Landroidx/compose/animation/core/KeyframesSpec$KeyframesSpecConfig; or its super classes
  (declaration of 'androidx.compose.animation.core.KeyframesSpec$KeyframesSpecConfig' appears in
  /data/app/~~rlFP4ThDS2yjsD1Xsh1cWQ==/es.jvbabi.vplanplus-6LDitHOwZpwGZt8Ywx6lFQ==/base.apk)
    at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt$CircularProgressIndicator$endAngle$1.invoke(ProgressIndicator.kt:302)
    at androidx.compose.material3.ProgressIndicatorKt$CircularProgressIndicator$endAngle$1.invoke(ProgressIndicator.kt:300)
```

These are my dependencies relevant to this issue:

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
```

No matter where I put them, they cause the app to crash.

Comment: Is compose enabled in the modules? `buildFeatures { compose true }`

Comment: Yes, it's active. Other components do work, except the ProgressImdicators

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using this version (confirmed it works) or a newer one should fix the issue.
[See all versions on mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.compose.material3/material3)

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-alpha10")
```

Comment: This has bugs with the animateItemPlacement

Comment: what is that? I use `group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3"` right now, do I need to switch to `material3-android` instead?

Comment: ok, I still can use `"androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta02"`, no need to use `material3-android`

Answer (score 12):

It's a known issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322214617
As a temporary solution, you can use this declaration in your Gradle file

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.0-rc01")
```

instead of

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
```

Comment: Now it's fixed in "compose-bom:2024.02.00" 
So, you can use:
`implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2024.02.00"))`
`implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")`
And it works

Answer (score 5):

chage `implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.6.0-alpha08")` to `1.6.0-alpha07`, it work for me, maybe it has a bug in `1.6.0-alpha08`

Comment: agreed, for me it was the version 1.6.0-alpha08

debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.6.0-alpha08"), replace it with alpha07 it works, also I just added the bom implementation

Comment: can confirm, version 1.6.0-rc01 is still causing my app to crash

Answer (score 3):

Switching to this made it work:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-beta02"
```

Comment: There is now also a rc version available

Comment: 1.2.0-rc01: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.2.0-rc01

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my side, and **it seems** there might be a bug between *material3* and the *materialIconsExtendedAndroid*.

I encountered this when trying to update:

```
composeBom = "2023.10.01"
materialIconsExtendedAndroid = "1.5.4"
```

to:

```
composeBom = "2024.01.00"
materialIconsExtendedAndroid = "1.6.0"
```

It would be wise to check on compatibility of the dependencies. Based on personal preference, I recommend [using the Bill of Materials](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom) for compose

My answer is, there is a compatibility bug.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue, what resolved the issue is to add progress: Float in `CircularProgressIndicator()`
progress value should be 0.0 to 1.0

This will resolve the Crash but progress indicator will not move. For that you have to iterate over and gave some delay.

```
var progress by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0.1F) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
    for (i in 1..100) {
        progress = i.toFloat()/100F
        delay(50)
    }
}

CircularProgressIndicator(
    progress = progress,
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.Center)
        .size(50.dp),
    color = Color.Gray,
    strokeWidth = 5.dp,
)
```

[image: Image Link]